# Json Patch Request using Volley Android

Tags: android, android-volley, json-patch

I have the following code.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode source = mapper.readTree(oldJson);
JsonNode target = mapper.readTree(newJson);
JsonPatch patch = JsonDiff.asJsonPatch(source,target);
```

Now how can I send this patch object through Volley using Request.Method.PATCH?

I know how to send String and JsonObject GET/POST requests through Volley but couldn't figure out for the Patch Request.